# How to signal End-Of-File in the Linux Console Window of Visual Studio

Tags: linux, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In VS2019 we can build Linux Console Applications.  Under the Visual Studio debugger, they execute using the Linux Console Window, for stdin and stdout.

In a 'real' Linux shell the key stroke Ctrl-D indicates end of input to a console application.  Ctrl-D does not work in the Linux Console Window.  (Ctrl-D is taken by Visual Studio as the first key of a chord - at least using the default key bindings)

What keystroke do I need?

NOTE - I am NOT asking for Ctrl-Z here.  That would indicate end of input to a Windows console program running in a command prompt window.

Comment: The terminal/console is a separate application that passes user input to console applications. This has nothing to do with Visual studio. What *terminal* are you using? There's no `Linux Console Window`, there's the old Console or the new Windows Terminal

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos I followed the instructions in this blog. (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/) slightly adjusted because I think my version of VS2019 is a bit later than when the blog was written.

However, as shown in the screenshots there *is* a "Linux Console Window", in Visual Studio.  It turns up when you run under the debugger.  I can type console input there, and it arrives via stdin to my program.  stdout output is displayed in there.

I just don't know how to simulate EOF in it.

Comment: `Ctrl+D` is a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio. Have you tried running your application *outside* Visual Studio?

Comment: Running outside Visual Studio gives the standard Linux behavior where Ctrl-D == EOF.  This works in both 'real' Linux and WSL.  It is not a solution.  I want to run the program under the VS debugger; and I want to know how to send EOF to the program's stdin.